# Как при inner join двух таблиц можно вывести все строки первой таблицы при отсутствии строк во второй таблице?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как при  `inner join` двух таблиц можно вывести все строки первой таблицы при отсутствии строк во второй таблице. Т.е. если табличка `@ListNumber` пуста, то необходимо вывести все строки из первой (table1) таблицы. Как это можно реализовать?

```
-- dbo.ListNum - Пользовательский тип данных 
declare @ListNumber as dbo.ListNum

insert into @ListNumber values('1111'),('2222'),('3333')

select t.Num, sum(t.KOLVO) as kol 
from table1 t join @ListNum l
     on l.Num = t.Num
where t.column1 > 100
group by t.Num
```

Comment: Что-то вроде IF(T.my_col IS NULL, L.my_col, T.my_col) AS MY_COL1

Comment: если использовать left join вывдит всю первую табличку не смотря на параметр (вторая таблица, если в ней есть строки)

Comment: тогда это уже не **inner** join, а либо **left** join  или **right** join, скорее всего вам right join

Comment: ошибся в коменте выше)) правильно IF(L.my_col IS NULL
тогда если в L таблице NULL, то выведется значение из T

и правильно поправили, нужен LEFT JOIN в этом случае

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одним из вариантов может быть введение переменной-флага, чьё состояние устанавливается в зависимости от наличия/отсутствия строк в `@ListNumber`, и использование `left join` вместо `inner join` с проверкой флага в `where`:

```
declare @listEmpty bit;
if not exists (select * from @ListNumber)
    set @listEmpty = 1;

select t.Num, sum(t.KOLVO) as kol 
from table1 t
    left join @ListNumber l on l.Num = t.Num
where t.column1 > 100
    and (@listEmpty = 1 or l.Num is not NULL)
group by t.Num;
```

Еще один вариант - ветвление. Если в `@ListNumber` есть строки, то присоединять её, если нет - не присоединять:

```
if exists (select * from @ListNumber)
    select t.Num, sum(t.KOLVO) as kol 
    from table1 t
         join @ListNumber l on l.Num = t.Num
    where t.column1 > 100
    group by t.Num;
else
    select t.Num, sum(t.KOLVO) as kol 
    from table1 t
    where t.column1 > 100
    group by t.Num;
```

Comment: вариант с флагом лучше